# Boost asio ConstBufferSequence - c++ Templates

Tags: c++, templates, boost, boost-asio

I am hoping for some guidance regarding C++ templates. I have been using the `boost::asio` library for communication over TCP. Thus far, I have been using storage containers built into the boost::asio library. For instance:

```
boost::array<char, 128> buf;
boost::system::error_code error;
size_t len = socket.read_some(boost::asio::buffer(buf), error);
```

To read from a socket, I simply wrap a buffer of type `boost::asio::buffer` around my `boost::array` object. This works fine, but now I'd like to work in the reverse direction. That is, I'd like to write back into the socket, pulling data from some custom storage classes I already have. **My question is, how do I make sense of the template type requirements required to be wrappable by boost::asio::buffer, or more generally, the parameter type specified by:**

```
template<typename ConstBufferSequence>
std::size_t send(   
   const ConstBufferSequence & buffers
);
```

The [API](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/doc/html/boost_asio/reference.html) lists the requirements of a [ConstBufferSequence](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/ConstBufferSequence.html), but I can't make heads or tails of this. Can somebody help me understand? What methods would the type I want to pass to the "send" function need to expose?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`boost::asio::buffer` returns objects implementing the `ConstBufferSequence` and `MutableBufferSequence` concepts; it doesn't expect *you* to implement them. The concrete types you're allowed to pass to `buffer` are listed [here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/buffer.html).

Comment: Not exactly what I wanted, but made things clearer nonetheless. Thanks for the answer. :)

Answer (score 3):

Although boost::asio::buffer works OK if you have a contiguous set of bytes in memory that you want to use as a buffer, if you are using scatter/gather I/O --or in particular if you are using gather writes (scatter reads are much less common), you do need to have an object that behaves like a ConstBufferSequence.

[If Concepts had made it into the standard [sigh], you would need an object that implements the ConstBufferSequence concept]

Here is a snippet of code from the Codecs::DataDestination class in QuickFAST (http:://www.quickfast.org) that implements ConstBufferSequence:

```
class DataDestination
{
  /// @brief Support for asio gather writes: forward iterator through buffers
  ///
  /// The intent is for DataDestination to conform to the asio::ConstBufferSequence concept.
  /// This would allow it to be passed directly to the asio::write(v)
  /// Note the implication that if asynch writes are used the DataDestination must
  /// remain intact until the write completes.
  class const_iterator
  {
  public:
    /// @brief construct an iterator pointing into a DataDestination
    /// @param destination is the buffer-container
    /// @param position is the starting position for the iterator.
    const_iterator(const DataDestination & destination, size_t position)
      : destination_(destination)
      , position_(position)
    { 
    }
     /// @brief Point iterator to next buffer (preincrement)
    const_iterator & operator ++()
    {
      if(position_ < destination_.size())
      {
        ++position_;
      }
      return *this;
    }

    /// @brief Point iterator to next buffer (postincrement)
    const_iterator operator ++(int)
    {
      const_iterator result(*this);
      if(position_ < destination_.size())
      {
        ++position_;
      }
      return result;
    }

    /// @brief dereference the iterator to find the actual buffer
    boost::asio::const_buffer operator * () const
    {
      const WorkingBuffer & buffer(destination_[position_]);
      return boost::asio::const_buffer(buffer.begin(), buffer.size());
    }

    /// @brief dereference the iterator to find the actual buffer
    boost::asio::const_buffer operator -> () const
    {
      const WorkingBuffer & buffer(destination_[position_]);
        return boost::asio::const_buffer(buffer.begin(), buffer.size());
    }

    /// @brief compare iterators.
    /// @param rhs is the iterator to which this should be compared.
    bool operator == (const const_iterator & rhs) const
    {
      return position_ == rhs.position_;
    }

    /// @brief compare iterators.
    /// @param rhs is the iterator to which this should be compared.
    bool operator != (const const_iterator & rhs) const
    {
      return position_ != rhs.position_;
    }
  private:
    const_iterator & operator=(const_iterator &); // no autogenerated assignment

  private:
    const DataDestination & destination_;
    size_t position_;
  };

  /// @brief return iterator pointing to the first buffer.
  const_iterator begin()const
  {
    return const_iterator(*this, 0);
  }

  /// @brief return iterator pointing past the last buffer
  const_iterator end() const
  {
    return const_iterator(*this, used_);
  }
};
```